# How to interpret $x^2= 25-y^2$

Tags: graphing-functions

For a circle with radius of $5$, we know it is,

$$x^2 + y^2 = 25.$$

I can interpret it as $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ and $g(z)=25$, the final circle is when the two graph intersects with each other in 3D space.

> [image]

But how to interpret it when I transform it into this,

$$x^2 = 25 - y^2.$$

$f(x) = x^2$ is parabola in 2D space, $g(y) = 25 - y^2$ is another parabola in 2D space, the two parabola intersection will never be a circle, I know there is something wrong goes here, but I want to plot the two functions to see the circle shape.

Edit:After plotting the graph, I've got this

[image]

And if take a bird view, it shows the circle projected on xy plane

[image]

What I done wrong is I tried to draw $x^2$ part on the xy plane as I would normally do with y=$x^2$, but it seems I should use the Z variable to draw the graph z=$x^2$ instead of y=$x^2$.

Comment: The circle is when you take a horizontal cross section. 

Look up conic cross-sections.

Comment: "the two parabola intersection will never be a circle"  Why not?

Comment: In three-d space the intersection is not a circle as the altitude goes up and down.  But if you *ignore* the altitude and look at the behavior of only $x,y$ on the intersection and complete *ignore* the $z$ values. The intersection, which is the graph $z = x^2 = 25-y^2$ will be $\{(x,y,z)|z=x^2 =25-y^2\} = \{(x,y,z)| x^2 + y^2 = 25; z=25-y^2\}$.  ... You are not inetersecting that path with a plane, but you are *projecting* it *down* **into** a plane.

Comment: "The circle is when you take a horizontal cross section. Look up conic cross-sections. "  Actually it isn't.  But it's a warped circle that goes up and down.  But $x^2 + y^2 = 25=z+y^2$ is the graph of the intersection while $x^2 + y^2 = 25; z = 0$ is the graph of its *projection*  **into** the plane.

Comment: Think of a horse on a merry-go-round.  That is your second intersection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REBOOT (you can see my earlier posts in the edit).

The intersection of $z = x^2 + y^2$ and $z=25$ is $x^2 + y^2 = z =25$.  That is a circle floating $25$ feet in the air.

The intersection of $z = x^2$ and $z= 25-y^2$ is $z = x^2 = 25-y^2$ or $x^2 + y^2 = 25 = z+y^2$.  That is a horse on a merry-go-round.  The horse's pole goes around in a circle while the horse itself goes up and down.

===== tl;dr =======

REBOOT (you can see my earlier posts in the edit).

If we consider a curve in $2$D space as $^1C = \{(x,y)|$ some relation between $x,y\}$ this exists entirely in the $x,y$ plane.

If we consider this as somehow related to curve $^2C_1$ in $3$D space where $^2C_1 = \{(x,y,z)|$ the same relationship between $x,y$ but also a $3$rd dimension $z$ is related somehow$\}$ then the we are considering $^1C$ and a ***projection*** of $^2C_1$ from the $x,y,z$ $3$D space down into $^1C$ in the $x,y$ $2$ D plane. via projection $\iota: (x,y,z) = (x,y)$  and $^1C = \iota(^2C_1)$.

This is fine. The $z$ value is *ignored*.

So if we consider $^2C_1$ is the intersection of the parabloid graph of $f(x,y) = x^2 + x^2$ and planar graph $g(x) = 25$ the intersection of a parabloid and a plane perpendicular to the axis of symmetry of the parabloid is a circle.

And indeed we get $^2C_1= \{(x,y,z)|x^2 + y^2 = z = 25\} =\{(x,y, 25)| x^2 + y^2= 25\}$; a circle floating $25$ feet in the air.  And if we project it down to the $x,y$ plane get $\iota ^2C_1 = \{(x,y)| x^2 + y^2=25$ and we completely ignore $z\}=S=\{(x,y)| x^2 + y^2 = 25\}$; a circle... the exact same circle in every way but we've pushed it down onto the ground.

Projecting a curve from a plane $z=25$ to the $x,y$ plane (which if we viewed it as part of 3D space would be $z=0$) is trivial an we do it without thinking; the $z$ doesn't matter, it could be $0$ or $25$ or $-\sqrt \pi$ for all we care, we're just shifting the curve up or down.

But a projection is *ignoring* the $z$ value, which is different than assuming it is a constant.

If $^2C_2 = \{(x,y,z)|$ some relation between $x,y,$ and $z$ and $z$ can go up and down then $\iota ^2C_2 =\{(x,y)|$ the same relation between $x,y$ but the $z$ value is ignored$\}$ is a projection shadow information is lost.

So if we consider you two functions in $3$D space.

$f(x,y) = x^2$ and $g(x,y)=25 -y^2$.  The graph of $f(x,y)$ is parabola shaped valley that cuts through $3$D space.  It's a parabola that extends into the third dimension along the $y$ axis.  And $g(x)$ is the same thing, but upside down and extending along the $x$ axis.

We can intersect them and the curve will be $^2C_2=\{(x,y,z)| z= x^2 =25 - y^2\}$.  What does this curve look like.  It's probably not a circle.  And if we manipulate symbols $^2C_2 = \{(x,y,z)| x^2 + y^2 = 25 = z+y^2\}$. That is is .... well it's the path of a person riding on a merry-go-round.  $x^2 +y^2 = 25$ so the horsey-pole goes around in circle, but the horse goes up and down from $y=0$ and $z =25$ to $y=5$ and $z= 0$.

Okay.... so what does this look like when we ignore the $z$ up-down motion and *project* it into the $x,y$ plane.

Well, it is $\iota ^2C_2 = \{(x,y)|x^2 + y^2 = 25$ and we completely ignore that $z = 25 + y^2\}=\{(x,y)|x^2 +y^2 =25\} = S$.  That's the exact same circle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will edit my questions and plot the graph later after I got home

Comment: I've edited my question in Edit part, I forgot to use the Z variable, could you please have a look to see if my final graph is correct?

Comment: If you are graphin in 3-d you must graph in 3-d.  the functions you describe in 2-d as $f(x) = x^2$ and $g(y) = 25-y^2$ must, in 3-d, be expressed as $f(x,y) = x^2$ (the $y$ value is ignored and this result in the 2-d graph of $z=f(x)=x^2$ being replicated infinitely along the $y$-axis, and as $g(x,y)=25-y^2$ where the $x$ value is ignored and the 2-d graph is replicated infinitely along the $x$-axis. The thing you, me, and eric all overlooked is the intersection doesn't have to be a circle.  It just has to be something that *projects* **down** onto a circle.